# Como posso forçar uma aplicação back-end a lançar um erro para testar com Jest?

Tags: javascript, jest

Preciso que a função userService.findByPk lance uma exceção para entrar no catch e assim retornar o status 500 e testar isso com o Jest.

```js
const findByPk = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const result = await userService.findByPk(id);
    if (!result) return res.status(404).json({ message: 'User does not exist' });
    return res.status(200).json(result);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: ERROR_MESSAGE });
  }
};
```

Tentei fazer o teste dessa forma mais não funciona, continua retornando status 200:

```js
    const userService = require('../../src/services/userService');
    
    it('É exibida a mensagem correta em caso de erro da aplicação', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(userService, 'findByPk').mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.reject('fail'));

        const { json: { token } } = await frisby.post(`${apiURL}/login`, { 
            email: 'lewishamilton@gmail.com',
            password: '123456',
        }).expect('status', 200);

        const { body } = await frisby
        .setup({
            request: {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': token
                }
            }
        })
        .get(`${apiURL}/user/1`)
        .expect('status', 500);
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizando a lib [sinon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon).

Segue abaixo um exemplo de como implementar, supondo que possui um arquivo de testes, basta importar o método que deseja "mockar" e o retorno que deseja que o método retorne, após isso basta fazer os asserts de acordo com o resultado que espera.

Utilizando o seu código como exemplo, seria alguma coisa como o seguinte:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const userService = require('../../src/services/userService');
// ...
it('É exibida a mensagem correta em caso de erro da aplicação', async () => {
    const mocked_error_from_hash_password = {
        severity: 'ERROR',
        code: '42P01',
        detail: 'The value of "keylen" is out of range. It must be >= 0 && <= 2147483647.',
        message: 'erro mockado'
     };
     const stub = sinon.stub(userService , "findByPk").yields(new Error(mocked_error_from_hash_password));
     //fazer o seu assert após fazer o stub do método
     //aqui idealmente seria chamado o endpoint que utiliza a função findByPk.
     //depois de fazer os asserts, fazer o "restore" do stub (desfazer o mock)
     stub.restore();
  });
```

Também é possível utilizar as funções resolve e reject de acordo com o que necessita, caso utilize promises.

Um exemplo de como executar utilizando promises é o seguinte:

```
const pg = require('../lib/postgres');
const server = app.listen();

it('Check norma list all gives 500 status code', (done) => {
    const mocked_error_from_database = {
          length: 107,
          severity: 'ERROR',
          code: '42P01',
          detail: 'mocked database error',
          position: '61',
          file: 'parse_relation.c',
          line: '1373',
          routine: 'parserOpenTable'
    };
    const stub = sinon.stub(pg, 'query').rejects(mocked_error_from_database);
            api.get(urlprefix)
                .set('Accept', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
                .set('Authorization', token)
                .expect(500)
                .end((err, res) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    stub.restore();
                    expect(res.body).to.have.property('errors');
                    expect(res.body.errors).to.be.an('array');
                    expect(res.body.errors[0]).to.have.property('msg');
                    expect(res.body.errors[0].msg).equal('Could not query table norma. Detail: mocked database error');
                    done();
                });
        });
```

Basicamente seriam essas as ações, neste exemplo utilizei a função `stub.rejects`, porque em meu código utilizei `promises`.

No primeiro exemplo utilizei a função `stub.yields` pois em meu código estava utilizando callbacks.

Existem muitas outras possíbilidades basta consultar a [documentação](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/).

Caso queira uma explicação detalhada com exemplos completos de código e explicações pode consultar esta [postagem](https://danizavtz.com.br/como-aumentar-a-cobertura-dos-testes-de-seu-codigo-com-sinon/)

Caso queira verificar código fonte, pode ver este [repositório](https://github.com/danizavtz/tokenAuth)